# defaulting a read input to a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to default a read -p input to a variable that was used earlier on in a script. Using this as example

```
read -p "Enter your name [Richard]: " name
```

but I want to do something like

```
read -p "Enter your name "[$name_that_was_used_before]": " name
```

Is there anyway of doing this within the same read line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only like this:

```
read -p "Enter your name "[$name_that_was_used_before]": " name; name=${name:-$name_that_was_used_before}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

name_that_was_used_before=John

read -p "Enter your name : " name

printf 'Hello %s!\n' "${name:-$name_that_was_used_before}"
```

- If no input is given, it defaults to *John*
- The `:-` is a form of Parameter Expansion.
- If that is not what you wanted, please clarify and explain your question.